# Cannot able to store value in a array - VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to store a filename in a array but i am getting Type mismatch error. I have changed the data type but it didn't work. Kindly help.

The code block that is throwing error,

```
Sub Example2()
Dim objFile,objFile1,objFolder,objFolder1 As Object
Dim splitting, counter, filename, filename1, splitting1, counter1,As Variant
Dim myarray() As Variant

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

splitting = Split(objFile.Name, "\", 9)

counter = UBound(splitting)

filename = splitting(counter)

    For Each objFile1 In objFolder1.Files

    splitting1 = Split(objFile1.Name, "\", 9)

    counter1 = UBound(splitting1)

    filename1 = splitting1(counter1)
    
    If srch1 = srch2 Then
    
    ReDim Preserve myarray(UBound(myarray) + 1)
    
    myarray() = filename1

    End If
    
    Next

    Next
```

Comment: You need to provide an Index when you want to assign something to an array member. Use `myarray(ubound(myarray)) = filename1`

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks. But now i am getting subscript out of range error at Redim preserve line.

Comment: When declaring in one line you have to do e.g. `Dim objFile As Object , objFile1 As Object`. You are using the objects in the `For Each loop` while you haven't created a reference to the `FileSystemObject` object. You are splitting the `File Name` instead of the `File Path`, which you don't have to do, because the `File Name` is simply returned by e.g. `objFile.Name`. You're doing another loop within a loop which will also be not necessary.  The answer provided would help you if the previous was correct. You should try to better explain what you're trying to do. Try my solution and ask away.

Comment: @VBasic2008, i am trying to compare all the similar file names within the folder for change in revisions. If there is change in revision, previous revision should be moved to another folder. That's why i am using loop within the loop. Eg: M98-2323-01A is compared with M98-2323-01C and the former is moved as it is an earlier version.

Comment: I've added another example for you to study. I'll be looking for a solution according to the comment shortly.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for the solution provided under Edit. You have simplified my code to a huge extent. Now i will try to work on the name comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get File Paths (to Array) Function

**Links**

[Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/objects-visual-basic-for-applications)
[FileSystemObject Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object)
[GetFolder Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getfolder-method)
[File Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/file-object)

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getFilePaths(ByVal FolderPath As String, _
                      Optional ByVal FirstIndex As Long = 1) _
         As Variant
    
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fsoFldr As Object
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim LastIndex As Long
    LastIndex = FirstIndex - 1
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
        LastIndex = LastIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve Data(FirstIndex To LastIndex)
        Data(LastIndex) = fsoFile.Path ' or .Name, .ParentFolder ...
    Next fsoFile
    
    getFilePaths = Data

End Function

Sub TESTgetFilePath()
    
    ' Define Folder Path ('fPath').
    Const fPath As String = "F:\Test\2020"
    ' Populate File Paths Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = getFilePaths(fPath)
    ' Validate File Paths Array.
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbCritical, "Fail"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Write title to the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
    Debug.Print "The List"
    ' Write values from File Paths Array to a String ('Result').
    Dim Result As String
    Result = Join(Data, vbLf)
    ' Write file paths to the Immediate window (CTRL+G).
    Debug.Print Result

End Sub
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
Sub Example2()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Dim LastIndex As Long
    LastIndex = -1
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        LastIndex = LastIndex + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(LastIndex)
        MyArray(LastIndex) = objFile.Name
    Next objFile
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Debug.Print n, MyArray(n)
    Next n

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Sub Example3()
    
    ' For a fileformat aaa-bbb-rev*.*, where 'rev' is to be tested if greater.
    ' Two hyphens only.
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\64568450"
    Const fSep As String = "-"
    Dim pSep As String
    pSep = Application.PathSeparator
     
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
    Dim FileParts As Variant ' An array containing the split file name.
    Dim fName As String      ' File part before the 2nd hyphen (minus) '-'
    Dim fRevision As String  ' File part after the 2nd hyphen (minus) '-'
    
    Dim LastIndex As Long
    LastIndex = -1
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    
    ' Write file paths to array.
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        FileParts = Split(objFile.Name, fSep)
        fName = FileParts(0) & fSep & FileParts(1)
        fRevision = FileParts(2)
        If Not dict.Exists(fName) Then
            dict(fName) = fRevision
        Else
            LastIndex = LastIndex + 1
            ReDim Preserve MyArray(LastIndex)
            If dict(fName) < fRevision Then
                MyArray(LastIndex) = FolderPath & pSep & fName _
                                                & fSep & fRevision
                dict(fName) = fRevision
            Else
                MyArray(LastIndex) = objFile.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next objFile
    
    ' Now 'MyArray' contains the list of file paths of the files to be moved.
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Debug.Print n, MyArray(n)
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for always providing help. Based on the solutions provided by Wasif, when i run the code i am getting Subscript out of range error. Any suggestion to rectify it

Comment: @Sandy: I've added another version to my answer. This should do the trick. I think without the [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) your in for a series of headaches.

Comment: thank you. Just small update, when we capture the filename it contains the file extension(.doc,.pdf etc). I think splitting before and after . might be more suitable and also the revision is always before the . file extension

Comment: all the files in the folder will be of same file type. But Thank you for the info.

Comment: If you remove the extension, you will have to add it later. Keep in mind that when you e.g. compare `A1E` and `B1Z`, the result will be the same as if you compared `A1E.xls` and `B1Z.pdf`. Also you could use `InstrRev` to get the position of the last hyphen or/and the last dot.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in VBA can be either static or dynamic.

A **static** array is declared with a fixed size:

```
Dim myStaticArr(10) As String
```

declares an array with a fixed number of members (usually 11 as the lower index starts at 0, but you can overwrite this).
If you want to be sure about the lower index, you can specify

```
Dim myStaticArr(1 to 10) As String
```

Now you have 10 elements (from 1 to 10).

Similar, a multidimensional array can be defined

```
Dim myStaticArr3D(1 to 10, 1 to 5, 1 to 8) As String
```

Now you have an array with 10 * 5 * 8 members.

All of these arrays have in common that you need to declare at compile time the size of the array. The VBA compiler will reserve the necessary amount of memory and you cannot resize it.

If you don't know at compile time how large your array will be, you can declare it as **dynamic** array (as you do)

```
Dim myDynamicArr() as String
```

This reserves no memory at all. Before you can write something into the array, you need to tell VBA how big the array will be. This is done using the `Redim` statement. Easiest form:

```
Redim myDynamicArr(1 to 10) as String
```

Usually, this is done after calculating the size needed, so you will usually find the `Redim` having a variable that was used to calculate the needed size:

```
Redim myDynamicArr(1 to sizeNeeded) as String
```

Now there are cases where you find at runtime that the needed size is too small. You can issue another `Redim` to increase the size - but as you want to keep the content of the array, you specify the option `Preserve`:

```
Redim Preserve myDynamicArr(1 to 2*sizeNeeded) as String
```

This will double the size and keep the content of the first members (omitting the `Preserve` option will double the size but the content of the existing members will get lost).

To get the current size of an array, you can use the functions `LBound` and `UBound`. This can be used on static and dynamic arrays:

```
Dim myStaticArr(5 to 99) As String
Debug.Print LBound(myStaticArr), UBound(myStaticArr)
>> 5 99
Dim myDynamicArr() As String
ReDim myDynamicArr(1 to 20) 
Debug.Print LBound(myDynamicArr), UBound(myDynamicArr)
>> 1 20
```

However, if you have a dynamic array and you never assigned memory to it, the functions `LBound` and `UBound` will throw a runtime error 9 "Subscript out of range"

---

Now what you want to do is to increase the size of the array by 1 every time you find a new value. You achieve this with

```
ReDim Preserve myarray(UBound(myarray) + 1)
```

which will look to the current size of the array using the `UBound`-function and resize it by 1, preserving its contents. That's fine, except for the fact that the very first time this statement is hit, the size of the array is undefined.

The easiest way to handle this is to use a variable that keeps track of your array size:

```
Dim myArray() as String, myArraySize as Long
(...)

myArraySize = myArraySize + 1
ReDim Preserve myArray(1 to myArraySize)
myarray(myArraySize) = filename1
```

One remark: `ReDim Preserve` is a rather expensive command. If you are dealing with a few entries, this doesn't matter, but if you are dealing with 100s or 1000s of elements, you should consider to use a [`Collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object).

Comment: The last sentence did it for me. I always forget that there are collections. Since we are dealing with files in a folder, they have to be unique, so a collection or another dictionary (which I prefer) would have been more appropriate than the array.

Answer (score 1):

You should index to the array to set the value after Redim:

```
ReDim Preserve myarray(UBound(myarray) + 1)
myarray(ubound(myarray)) = filename1
```

VBA arrays are so finicky and frustrating. I would add items to a string and after then split it to an array:

```
Dim strArray As String
strArray = ""
REM .....
strArray = strArray + filename1 + ","
REM .....
myarray = Split(strArray,",")
```