# ListArray in VBA

Tags: vba

I try to write strings into a list

```
Sub test()
Dim x() As String
For j = 1 To 5
    x(j) = "Number" & j
Next j
End Sub
```

and get the message "Subscript out of Range". Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the snippet and how I can solve it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570708/7599798

Comment: thanks that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have to ReDim your Array.

With your Code your Array has no Length defined, thats why you get the Error message **Subscript out of Range**
If you know the exact length before you have to define your array like this:

```
Dim  x(5) As String
```

If you want this to stay dynamic, try the following Code, every iteration we make your Array one step bigger

```
Sub test()
Dim x() As String
Dim j As Integer

For j = 1 To 5
    ReDim x(j) //Here change the Length of the Array
    x(j) = "Number" & j
Next j
End Sub
```